# How to completely remove database connection in sqlalchemy? Giving max_user_limit on python anywhere

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy, pythonanywhere

I am hosting a flask application on Pythonanywhere. Where I have to make few queries from the database. While using MySQLdb I am able to close all the connection to database and don't get any error. But while using sqlalchemy some how connections to the database do not get closed.

This is my connection manager class which has a method defined to close the database connection.

```
class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base = declarative_base()

    def get_db_session(self):
        self.engine = create_engine(get_db_path())
        self.base.metadata.bind = self.engine
        self.session_maker = sessionmaker(bind = self.engine)
        self.session = self.session_maker()
        return self.session

    def persist_in_db(self,record):
        session = self.get_db_session()
        session.add(record)
        session.commit()
        session.close()

    def close_session(self):
        self.session.close()
        self.session_maker.close_all()
        del self.session
        del self.session_maker
        del self.engine
       #self.engine.dispose()
```

Before returning the response form the app I call close_session method.
So my question basically is where I am conceptually getting wrong and how can I completely remove database connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by [connection pooling](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html). You can disable connection pooling by using [`NullPool`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.NullPool).

```
self.engine = create_engine(get_db_path(), poolclass=NullPool)
```

Be careful though, this may not be a good idea in a web app if each web request needs a DB connection.

Comment: Okay, so what is the best practice here which should be considered. Is creating a engine as global is correct. And also what if we get race conditions?

Comment: @user2738777 Creating an engine globally is correct. Using a connection pool is thread-safe, provided that you don't share access to a single connection checked out from the pool. If you're using flask, the common thing to do is to use flask-sqlalchemy. It takes care of handling the session lifecycle and correctly creates and destroys sessions in each incoming request.